# How do I change the font of a TextInput in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I have tried changing fonts inside TextInput with:

```
inputStyle: {
    fontFamily: 'sans-serif-condensed',
}
```

It doesn't seem to be working. It's working fine on regular Text fields.

Does anyone have an idea why?

I am using react-native 0.15.0 and testing on an android device.